# Vaadin SQLContainer Refreshing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

The [Vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/sqlcontainer.caching.html) says:

> Normally, the SQLContainer will handle refreshing automatically when required.

However, where is this defined? How often will the container refresh?

I have tried to test this but unable to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check [SQLContainer](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/addons/SQLContainer/trunk/src/com/vaadin/addon/sqlcontainer/SQLContainer.java) code.

The phrase

> Normally, the SQLContainer will handle refreshing automatically when
>   required.

means SQLContainer will refresh itself after some changes made to it's state. For example, after adding *orderBy* **refresh()** will be called:

```
   /**
     * Adds the given OrderBy to this container and refreshes the container
     * contents with the new sorting rules.
     * 
     * Note that orderBy.getColumn() must return a column name that exists in
     * this container.
     * 
     * @param orderBy
     *            OrderBy to be added to the container sorting rules
     */
    public void addOrderBy(OrderBy orderBy) {
        if (orderBy == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!propertyIds.contains(orderBy.getColumn())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The column given for sorting does not exist in this container.");
        }
        sorters.add(orderBy);
        refresh();
    }
```

This is true for all other operations (please note **refresh()** call):

```
  public void rollback() throws UnsupportedOperationException, SQLException {
        debug(null, "Rolling back changes...");
        removedItems.clear();
        addedItems.clear();
        modifiedItems.clear();
        refresh();
    }
```